# Which is the recommended groovy plugin for Emacs?

Tags: emacs, groovy

When looking for a simple groovy mode plugin for emacs to get indenting and some form of syntax highlighting, I found [3 version on the groovy website](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Emacs+Plugin).

This page is excellent at giving the overview and some down in the weeds details, however is a bit skimpy on why to choose one over the other.

There is Jeremy Rayner's **groovy-mode.el**  which *isn't painful*

There is Russel Winder's identically named **groovy-mode.el** which is based on cc-mode.

There Stuart Clayman inferioir groovy mode **inf-groovy.el**

Currently I am drawn toward Jeremy's plugin, but I feel that being *not painful* is a poor reason to choose one over the others.

I'd like to know which ones are recommended or which ones are to be avoided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Jeremy Ranyer's `groovy-mode.el` for the sole reason that it worked better with my code then Russel Winder's version, at the time I tested them.

Here's a small modification I've added to Rayner's that fixes some problems (the elvis operator, if I recall correctly):

```
(defconst groovy-block-mid-re
   "need something here or it blows up"
   )
```

Comment: I am evaluating it now. There is something with the electric-indent with inline closures which bothers me. For the rest it works fine for now.

Answer (score 7):

Things changed a bit since ataylor's answer: now *(March 2017)* [the official Groovy website](http://groovy-lang.org/ides.html) links to Emacs-Groovy-Mode which combines Russel Winder's and Stuart Clayman's work.

As we may expect, the [repo is available on Github](https://github.com/Groovy-Emacs-Modes/groovy-emacs-modes).

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/russel/groovy-emacs-modes) the new repo? The one linked is not on github anymore.

Comment: It seems so, but It's a fork of https://github.com/Groovy-Emacs-Modes/groovy-emacs-modes, updating the answer